# Wikidata on all Trump's executive orders

Tags: wikidata

I'd like a wikidata query that returns all executive orders signed by President Trump.

This query gets *all* executive orders:

https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Forder%20%3ForderLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Forder%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ1338798.%0A%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D

I think it should be possible by using the executive order number and limiting the executive orders to one with a number above 13764.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT ?order ?orderLabel WHERE {
  ?order wdt:P31 wd:Q1338798.
  ?order wdt:P50 wd:Q22686
 SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

[on Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Forder%20%3ForderLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Forder%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ1338798.%0A%20%20%3Forder%20wdt%3AP50%20wd%3AQ22686%0A%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

However, apparently many of Trump's executive orders currently do not have Wikidata items and therefore won't appear in the results, e.g. [Executive Order 13819](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Executive_Order_13819), so you might want use other sources like [List of executive actions by Donald Trump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_executive_actions_by_Donald_Trump).